I wanted to get a array of objects in a flat sturcture for the parent it's child and it's grand child and it's great grandchild and so on
I have an array of objects like below, I have just given an example of level 3 but it might have more:
[{Portfolio:"AMBAL",
 Level:1,
 Immediate Parent:""},
{Portfolio:"AMBAL-PI",
 Level:2,
 Immediate Parent:"AMBAL"},
{Portfolio:"AMBAL-FI",
 Level:2,
 Immediate Parent:"AMBAL"},

{Portfolio:"2213AMBAL",
 Level:3,
 Immediate Parent:"AMBAL-FI"},
{Portfolio:"2132AMBAL",
 Level:3,
 Immediate Parent:"AMBAL-PI"}....]


Expected o/p

[{Portfolio:"AMBAL",
 Level:1,
 Immediate Parent:""},

{Portfolio:"AMBAL-FI",
 Level:2,
 Immediate Parent:"AMBAL"},

{Portfolio:"2213AMBAL",
 Level:3,
 Immediate Parent:"AMBAL-FI"},

{Portfolio:"AMBAL-PI",
 Level:2,
 Immediate Parent:"AMBAL"},

{Portfolio:"2132AMBAL",
 Level:3,
 Immediate Parent:"AMBAL-PI"}

]

How can I return the above array of objects using javascript only?

You could collect per level and get a flat array.


const
    data = [{ Portfolio: "AMBAL", Level: 1, "Immediate Parent": "" }, { Portfolio: "AMBAL-PI", Level: 2, "Immediate Parent": "AMBAL" }, { Portfolio: "AMBAL-FI", Level: 2, "Immediate Parent": "AMBAL" }, { Portfolio: "2213AMBAL", Level: 3, "Immediate Parent": "AMBAL-FI" }, { Portfolio: "2132AMBAL", Level: 3, "Immediate Parent": "AMBAL-PI" }],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            r[o["Immediate Parent"]].push([o, r[o.Portfolio] = []]);
            return r;
        }, { '': [] })
        ['']
        .flat(Infinity);

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }



